# GWT + AppEngine app in dev mode not available on local network

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm developing an GWT + AppEngine app. All works well except when I run it in dev mode the app is not visible to machine on local network.

Even on local machine http://localhost:8080/app is working, while http://192.168.x.x:8080/app is not available.

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `-a 0.0.0.0` to your appengine configuration

Answer (score 2):

This mode is especially useful when you need to debug a mobile application. The official way to do this is using the command argument when launching the application:

-bindAddress 0.0.0.0

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM

With Eclipse, you can setup this in Run configuration - Arguments - Program arguments